# What code should I use to get & (not &amp;) in the tweet?

Tags: iphone, mgtwitterengine, twitter-oauth

I use [Twitter-OAuth-iPhone](https://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone) to POST tweets by `[_engine sendUpdate:myText];`, which works fine. However, the letter `&` in the 'myText' will be changed to `&amp;` in the tweet shown on Twitter.com. The `&` is for coordinates link: `@"http://maps.google.co.uk/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=%f,+%f"`.

I tried to replace the `&` with `%%26` in the 'myText', which turns out with `%26` in the tweet instead of `&`; and when I replace with `%26`, the app crash.

What code should I use to get `&` (not `&amp;`) in the tweet?

Comment: Crash? I guess it's a bug of the library.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use a URL shortener, since Twitter may be doing something to avoid SQL injection and the like.

Otherwise, does this work for you?

```
- (NSString *)stringByReplacingPercentEscapesFromString:(NSString *)inString
{
    NSString *outString = (NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByReplacingPercentEscapes(NULL, (CFStringRef)inString, CFSTR(""));
    return [outString autorelease];
}
```

Comment: Hi josh thanks, but the code does not get & in the tweet as well. How should I use URL shortener in the code?

Comment: You should be able to call out to any of the url shorteners with the url you need to post to twitter, get back a "clean" url, and then post that. See this SO thread for implementation details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252470/implementing-url-shorteners-in-my-iphone-application